# How can i pass a parameters to action method using javascript fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using js `fetch` to call to an action method(in asp.net mvc),
but I need to pass parameters to the method.

How can I pass this data using `fetch`?

I'm trying to use this code but the data didn't pass:

```
fetch(url, {
    data: { repositoryName: "dada" }
})
.then(() => {
   console.log("test");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.github.io/fetch/#options) second parameter shouldn't contain `data` property.

I guess you need to use `body` property(you can use JSON string, `FormData` or `URLSearchParams` here basing on your needs, see [docs](https://github.github.io/fetch/#request-body)):

```
fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ repositoryName: "dada" })        
}).then(() => { ... })
```

Also in this simple example it's possible to simply use query string like this:

```
fetch(url + '?repositoryName=dada').then(() => { ... })
```

**Note** that GET requests cannot have body so if your MVC action is GET action then you have to use query strings like in my second example.